# Unity buttons needs two presses to be executed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

When i add OnScreenStick or OnScreenButton to a GameObject that is turned off and on, unity buttons for some reason needs to be double pressed (On PC) in order for it to execute.

---

The cause of this is this function : SetupInputControl() which executes OnEnable for this script, which is part of the unity new input system plugin.

Packages\InputSystem\Plugins\OnScreen\OnScreenControl.cs

---

I tried very hard to try to figure out what to modify in this function to make this problem go away, but i failed.

---

```
    private void SetupInputControl()
    {
        Debug.Assert(m_Control == null, "InputControl already initialized");
        Debug.Assert(m_NextControlOnDevice == null, "Previous InputControl has not been properly uninitialized (m_NextControlOnDevice still set)");
        Debug.Assert(!m_InputEventPtr.valid, "Previous InputControl has not been properly uninitialized (m_InputEventPtr still set)");

        // Nothing to do if we don't have a control path.
        var path = controlPathInternal;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            return;

        // Determine what type of device to work with.
        var layoutName = InputControlPath.TryGetDeviceLayout(path);
        if (layoutName == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError(
                $"Cannot determine device layout to use based on control path '{path}' used in {GetType().Name} component",
                this);
            return;
        }

        // Try to find existing on-screen device that matches.
        var internedLayoutName = new InternedString(layoutName);
        var deviceInfoIndex = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < s_OnScreenDevices.length; ++i)
        {
            ////FIXME: this does not take things such as different device usages into account
            if (s_OnScreenDevices[i].device.m_Layout == internedLayoutName)
            {
                deviceInfoIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If we don't have a matching one, create a new one.
        InputDevice device;
        if (deviceInfoIndex == -1)
        {
            // Try to create device.
            try
            {
                device = InputSystem.AddDevice(layoutName);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.LogError(
                    $"Could not create device with layout '{layoutName}' used in '{GetType().Name}' component");
                Debug.LogException(exception);
                return;
            }
            InputSystem.AddDeviceUsage(device, "OnScreen");

            // Create event buffer.
            var buffer = StateEvent.From(device, out var eventPtr, Allocator.Persistent);

            // Add to list.
            deviceInfoIndex = s_OnScreenDevices.Append(new OnScreenDeviceInfo
            {
                eventPtr = eventPtr,
                buffer = buffer,
                device = device,
            });
        }
        else
        {
            device = s_OnScreenDevices[deviceInfoIndex].device;
        }

        // Try to find control on device.
        m_Control = InputControlPath.TryFindControl(device, path);
        if (m_Control == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError(
                $"Cannot find control with path '{path}' on device of type '{layoutName}' referenced by component '{GetType().Name}'",
                this);

            // Remove the device, if we just created one.
            if (s_OnScreenDevices[deviceInfoIndex].firstControl == null)
            {
                s_OnScreenDevices[deviceInfoIndex].Destroy();
                s_OnScreenDevices.RemoveAt(deviceInfoIndex);
            }

            return;
        }
        m_InputEventPtr = s_OnScreenDevices[deviceInfoIndex].eventPtr;

        // We have all we need. Permanently add us.
        s_OnScreenDevices[deviceInfoIndex] =
            s_OnScreenDevices[deviceInfoIndex].AddControl(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i upgraded to 2022.1.13f, it was solved.